# How to track expirations

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

Let me provide an example to make my question clear:

- We have a node app and in this case we have customer subscriptions. The default is that we subscribe a new customer to a trial (say 30days of trial) and in the db record there will be a trialExpiration date.
- After the trial expires we would like to move the customer to a free plan

It can be seen that the backend need to recognize the end of the trial period when the trial has expired. How to track the expiration date? What is the usual approach?

Well, for the last question I can answer, maybe the general approach is to check the expiration before every login and act accordingly. Another possibility is to have a cron like job which happens the exact time the expiration has ended.

Which is better and how to approach the cron-like solution?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, a `cron` job is preferable. Two reasons:

- You'll typically want other actions to be associated with an expiry—sending an email to the user that their account has expired, for example—which would not make any sense to have have happen when they arrive and sign in.
- You'll want your db records to be up to date for other purposes, say pulling statistics or billing runs.

To clarify on the second item above: imagine that you want to send an email announcing a change to user accounts (say a privacy policy update), but you don't want to send that email to users with an expired account. It's much easier to select all active accounts from the database, rather than needing to check against an expiration date. You might say, "well that's easy to add to my code", but: what happens if you have another system that uses this database, or a system that queries your system via an RPC, or maybe you just shell in and run some raw SQL? You suddenly need to replicate that expiration-checking code across many possible systems (or just places in your codebase), and checking an `active==True` is much simpler.

For information on jobs, I have another brief [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416832/sails-js-check-database-every-time/36417114#36417114) from a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to check for the expiration during login. The advantage we get by doing this is less overhead on the DB and no external scripts,triggers are required, this ensures better maintainable code.

Comment: Yes, but I don't like the idea of the possible backdoor of a user never logging out and always refreshing his session, so a login would not be initiated and the user could possibly be forever onto a higher level plan.

Comment: You have a very valid point there. In that scenario you pretty much have to have a request filter which does the check for you on all incoming requests. This will be a robust solution.